# Is smooth stack separated?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic stack. Is it true that $X$ is separated? I was searching on google but could not find the answer. Please provide a reference.

Answer (score 7):

No. The affine line with a double origin is a non-separated nonsingular scheme